# Handling dropdown with Submit button in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

From the code mentioned below, there would be two dropdown's (1 for Adding to Cricket(All of Students would be mentioned) and 2nd is for Removing Student from Cricket team ) and there are 2 Submit buttons (1 for Adding Student to Cricket and 2nd is to Remove Student) . If I select  Add Student dropdown and click on Add Button , then it should be submitted successfully.

```
<label class="labelcss" for="exampleInputEmail1">  Student  to Add for Cricket :   </label>   <form:select path="studentId">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select a Student    " />
    <c:forEach items="${studentList}"  var="student">
     <option value="${student.studentId}">${student.studentName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
  </form:select>    
    <br><br>
    <br>
<label class="labelcss" for="exampleInputEmail1">  Student  to Remove from Cricket Team:   </label>
<form:select path="studentId" >
     <form:option value="0" label="Select a Student     " />
     <c:forEach items="${studentsList}"  var="students">
       <option value="${students.studentId}">${students.studentName}</option>
      </c:forEach>
</form:select> 
<button type="submit" name ="add"class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
<button type="submit" name ="remove"class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
```

Please reply if the context is not clear or the code is not enough ... Thanks .

Comment: <label class="labelcss" for="exampleInputEmail1">  Student  to Add :   </label>
            <form:select path="studentId">
               <form:option value="0" label="Select a Student    " />
                   <c:forEach items="${studentList}"  var="student">
                      <option value="${student.studentId}">${student.studentName}</option>
                   </c:forEach>
              </form:select>  
              <br><br>
              <br>

Comment: <label class="labelcss" for="exampleInputEmail1">  Student  to Remove :   </label>
              
            <form:select path="studentId" >
               <form:option value="0" label="Select a Student     " />
                   <c:forEach items="${studentsList}"  var="students">
                      <option value="${students.studentId}">${students.studentName}</option>
                   </c:forEach>
              </form:select>

Comment: BTW what's your question?

Comment: are the elements actually in a `form` with a name?